# Create SVG using C# by overlaying one SVG icon onto another

Tags: c#, svg

How (if possible to do so) can I create an SVG image, using C#? I wish to take one SVG, overlay another SVG on it, and save it as a third SVG image.

In my specific case, I allow a module of my software to provide an icon for a folder. I want to overlay a warning or error icon on top of the folder icon when there is an error in the contained data.

Comment: "Create" and "Combine" are not exactly the same.

Comment: That's true @HenkHolterman. "Combine" might better describe what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It seems to be a very common question. Have you tried to google on "SVG combine" or "SVG stacking". Since SVG is XML, porting these answer to C# seems relatively easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [SVG Rendering Engine](http://svg.codeplex.com/) to do this. Create a third document, and put the two given svgs one after the other into it. (Nesting svg documents in each other is completely valid):

```
var icon = SvgDocument.Open(...);
var overlayIcon = SvgDocument.Open(...);

var overlayed = new SvgDocument();

overlayed.Children.Add(icon);
overlayed.Children.Add(overlayIcon);

overlayed.Write(...); // saving
```

Note: check the overlaying icon's size, viewbox, etc., you may have to change these through SvgDocument.Width, SvgDocument.Height, SvgDocument.ViewBox to get proper result.

Answer (score 1):

SVG is a very simple text format, even simpler than HTML. Overlaying SVGs is a work for XML library. You can just open it and append every node from one file to another file.

Just try taking these two text files:

- http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg
- http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg

Open the first one, copy contents of the the `<svg>...</svg>`, paste at the end of the other file (just before the ending `</svg>` tag). You can check in some editor or validator that the result is just a perfectly fine SVG file.

Use [`System.Xml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [`System.Xml.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) for handling it from your C# code. Additionally you can add new nodes, edit attributes like width, height, color, etc... if you want:

```
<svg width="637" height="637">
   <path style="fill:white" d="... "/>
   ...
</svg>
```

Have fun.